# Allowing User to send emails from 2 exchange addresses

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Curently running exchange, when a user opens outlook their personal emails appear along with their departments emails. So they can see personal emails and example accounts emails.

As it currently stands when the user replys to a email in the department folder it sends the email from their personal email rather than from the dertment email address..

I would like to be able to set it up in a way that when the user replys to email she can send it from the departments email. Eg Accounts@email.com dept instead of from joe.bloggs@email.com

Is this possible and what steps do i need to take to allow this to happen?

Is there going to be changes needed on the exchange side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that under active directory on the user group the user did not have Send As permissions. Thus not the user was not able to send emails from the account.

Comment: So my reply helped? :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the users allready have full-access permissions on the other account?
if joe.bloggs@email.com got the permissions (set on exchange) to accounts@email.com, he should be able to send from that address. Have you tried enabling the "from" field in outlook, and set it to send from "accounts@email.com"?

I've seen this behaviour go automatic with just setting "full-access"-permission on the exchange, and starting to write an e-mail (or replying!) from the inbox of the department inbox (in this example: accounts@email.com)

Comment: The problem is that the genernal accounts like accounts@gmail.com are set up as distrubation list on exchange. Is it still possible

Comment: I see! You can still set "send-as" permissions on a distro-group. Which allows for this to happen :-) Remember to activate the "from:" field in outlook and test!